# AJAX POST working but callbacks not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I checked many posts regarding this issue and tried different solutions, but none work for me, my AJAX POST is working which simply adds the email to my emailing list, but both my call backs success and error is not firing expect in unknown conditions or i can call it (randomly).

HTML:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input id="user_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Here" required>
    <button type="submit" onclick="onbtnclick()">SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mail.ayaami.com/freebook_10x10.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: send_data,
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert("Thank you for joining Ayaami mailing list.");
        window.open("http://dev.ayaami.com/site/free-book-success");

        // var value = responseData.someKey;
        //  console.log(' log d: '+responseData);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+textStatus);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+jqXHR);
        //  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData);
        // hide the email box 
        //      text_respond="<p>"+obj.result+"</p>";

        // set cookies 

        var cookieName = 'ayaami_newsletter_lightbox';
        var cookieValue = 'true';
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + (500 + 12));
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate +
            ";domain=.ayaami.com;path=/";
    },
    error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('You already subscribed in the mailing list.');
        console.log('log e:' + responseData);
        console.log('log e:' + textStatus);
        console.log('log e:' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I tried in success to popup an alert or redirect to another greeting page, none works, I removed the datatype before in the AJAX parameters still nothing changed.

Edition, wrapped with document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('#mybtn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mail.ayaami.com/freebook_10x10.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {email:$(this).parent().find('input').val()},
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert("Thank you for joining Ayaami mailing list.");
        window.open("http://dev.ayaami.com/site/free-book-success");

        // var value = responseData.someKey;
        //  console.log(' log d: '+responseData);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+textStatus);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+jqXHR);
        //  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData);
        // hide the email box 
        //      text_respond="<p>"+obj.result+"</p>";

        // set cookies 

        var cookieName = 'ayaami_newsletter_lightbox';
        var cookieValue = 'true';
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + (500 + 12));
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate +
            ";domain=.ayaami.com;path=/";
    },
    error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('You already subscribed in the mailing list.');
        console.log('log e:' + responseData);
        console.log('log e:' + textStatus);
        console.log('log e:' + errorThrown);
    }
});

});
```

}

Comment: why are you using ajax if you are redirecting to another page?

Comment: Can you add the code for  the onbtnclick function?

Comment: @madalinivascu that was one of the solutions I thought of, after all i need to give the users a feedback whether they could signup or not no matter I gave them alert or new page.

Comment: @dimlucas the code in "onbtnclick" function.

Comment: @SadiqJaffer what errors do you have in the console?

Comment: Just Unexpected token error, and few from other 3rd party.
This is the link: http://dev.ayaami.com/site/special-offer

Comment: Lol your ajax isn't even triggering

Comment: @madalinivascu lol is it? but it does adds the emails to my database.

Comment: @SadiqJaffer see my answer below

Comment: Is your Ajax error function triggering?

Comment: @SatejS as far as I see, NO it does not trigger.

Comment: @SadiqJaffer , i'm not sure how relevant this is, but this was on the documentation for the error handler.. `Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.`

Comment: Also, where is the unexpected token?

Comment: @SatejS overcome it, now after wrapping with document ready it's telling me it is not function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following, use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default redirect to page

```
  $(function(){
     $('body').on('click','.leka-button',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mail.ayaami.com/freebook_10x10.php',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {email:$(this).parent().find('input').val()},
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                alert("Thank you for joining Ayaami mailing list.");
                window.open("http://dev.ayaami.com/site/free-book-success");

                // var value = responseData.someKey;
                //  console.log(' log d: '+responseData);
                //  console.log(' log d: '+textStatus);
                //  console.log(' log d: '+jqXHR);
                //  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData);
                // hide the email box 
                //      text_respond="<p>"+obj.result+"</p>";

                // set cookies 

                var cookieName = 'ayaami_newsletter_lightbox';
                var cookieValue = 'true';
                var myDate = new Date();
                myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + (500 + 12));
                document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate +
                    ";domain=.ayaami.com;path=/";
            },
            error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('You already subscribed in the mailing list.');
                console.log('log e:' + responseData);
                console.log('log e:' + textStatus);
                console.log('log e:' + errorThrown);
            }
        });

        });
});
```

ps: remove the onclick function and change the type of the button to button

```
<button type="button">SIGN UP</button>
```

Comment: Removed onclick, and added id for the button and used your code, still nothing, take a look on the page to see.

Comment: Ouch, check the edited post again, is my implementation correct? because yet no result.

Comment: according to this ref https://api.jquery.com/ready/ , the way supposed to be fine but yet it is telling me it's not function.

Comment: Now much better, no error regarding the document ready or the ajax, but yet it didn't fire for me the success or error.

Comment: Will do few tests and let you know about the result.

Comment: For some reason i suspsected in the page itself as it may got conflicted with another library, i created a tester page in my main site: http://www.ayaami.com/site/test

And it pretty works BUT it always success and the error does not fire?

Comment: the error triggers if the ajax isn't successful,you ajax is successful thus triggers success

Comment: Not certainly sure about the PHP for backend as my mate wrote it, but I recall it supposed if it went to "else" case it considered as error.
`if($user_type=="new"){
 $message="You will receive an email with your first coupon code. Enjoy!";

}else {
 $message="Looks like you’re already on our mailing list! Enjoy!";


} `

Comment: your php code displays error ,can't help with that, post another question for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110349/discussion-between-sadiq-jaffer-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 5):

Irrespective of the error, don't use the success function, use the `.done()`,`.fail()`,`.always()` function.The code below is from the JQuery documentation.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Here is the text from the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **Deprecation Notice**
>   The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are
>   deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual
>   removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I replaced `.success` with `.done` and `.error` with `.fail`  but still same result, this time with an error `Unexpected token`  in .done line.

Comment: `success:function(data){}` is **not** deprecated `$.ajax().success()` is deprecated

Comment: @madalinivascu if I wrote after my AJAX directly success still giving me `Unexpected` token error. do you mind to modify the code so I know where is my fall down?

Comment: @madalinivascu, sorry did not notice that at first.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

1) In your code missing order form serializer as this like:

```
var send_data = $("#yourOrderFormId").serialize();
```

2) You have a wrong url

3) Missing dataType as this like: dataTypeL 'html' or you may use 'php'

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/freebook_10x10.php',  
    crossDomain: true,
    data: send_data,
    dataType: 'php',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert("Thank you for joining Ayaami mailing list.");
        window.open("http://dev.ayaami.com/site/free-book-success");

        // var value = responseData.someKey;
        //  console.log(' log d: '+responseData);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+textStatus);
        //  console.log(' log d: '+jqXHR);
        //  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData);
        // hide the email box 
        //      text_respond="<p>"+obj.result+"</p>";

        // set cookies 

        var cookieName = 'ayaami_newsletter_lightbox';
        var cookieValue = 'true';
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + (500 + 12));
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate +
            ";domain=.ayaami.com;path=/";
    },
    error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('You already subscribed in the mailing list.');
        console.log('log e:' + responseData);
        console.log('log e:' + textStatus);
        console.log('log e:' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: This is my send_data `var send_data = {email:user_email};` implementation, regarding the URL it is an external not in same domain.